# To find shower in Latvia

Tags: europe, hygiene, latvia

Is there any gasoline stations in Latvia that provides shower? I know I can get shower in swimming pool, but I need something that costs 5 Eur maximum. Where I can take shower in Riga?

Comment: I pay less than €5 for swimming in a pool in the Netherlands. I would be surprised if you pay that much in a pool in Latvia.

Comment: @Willeke Swimming pools are in many countries so cheap just because they are run as a  public service, or at least subsidised. The first two swimming pools I checked in Riga charge 12€ for a single visit, with one of them having a reduced entry fee of 10€ if you visit during 'low-traffic' hours.